# How to publish a Reactjs component to npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

**Goal:** I have a simple React component with two imports: `react` and `prop-types` and I'm trying to publish it to npm.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends Component {
   ...
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**Problem:** I've never published anything before, so I'm not sure how to set everything up. Below is what I've attempted - when I try testing it with `npm link`, I can successfully import the component but as soon as I try using it, it gives me the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

**File structure:**

```
├── node_modules/
├── lib/
|   ── index.js    <--- this is where webpack builds to
├── src/
|   ── index.js    <--- this is the react component
|
├── package.json
├── webpack.config.js
├── .babelrc
├── .npmignore
├── .gitignore
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "author": "...",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "..."
  },
  "homepage": "...",
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack file:**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry:  './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'react': 'commonjs react',
    'react-dom' : 'commonjs react-dom'
  }
};
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

**Importing:**

And, for clarification, I'm not mixing up default and named imports, the package is being imported as a default import:

```
import MyComponent from 'my-component';
```

Comment: Can you show how you import the component in the client code? Make sure you import it like this: `import MyComponent from 'mycomponent'` rather than like this: `import { MyComponent } from 'mycomponent'` since you're using `export default` in your module.

Comment: I'm importing it as a default import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpack config option `output.libraryTarget` can be used to tell webpack about the type of build it should create:

- `"commonjs2"`: The return value of your entry point will be assigned to the module.exports
- `"umd"`: results in a build that works with CommonJS, AMD and old-fashioned script tags/global variables (credit to [@JoeClay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5436257/joe-clay))

See the documentation here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#module-definition-systems

These settings will export your component as a CommonJS module that you can import as desired.

Comment: I'd recommend targeting `"umd"` instead of solely CommonJS - the former results in a build that works with CommonJS, AMD and old-fashioned script tags/global variables.

Comment: @forrert Thanks, what's the difference between commonjs and commonjs2? Should I use commonjs2 in my exports section as well?

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks, does that mean to add a "umd" property above the commonjs one in libraryTarget and inside externals ?

Comment: @linasmnew: Not above - instead of! `output.libraryTarget: "umd"`

Comment: @linasmnew: Also, [here's the difference between `commonjs` and `commonjs2`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114#issuecomment-105509929).